# Why is scrapy crawling a different facebook page?

Tags: python, facebook, scrapy

This is a scrapy spider.This spider is supposed to collect the names of all div nodes with class attribute=5d-5 essentially making a list of all people with x name from y location.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class fb_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name="fb"
    allowed_domains = ["facebook.com"]
    start_urls = [             
    "https://www.facebook.com/search/people/?q=jaslyn%20california"]

     def parse(self,response):
         x=response.xpath('//div[@class="_5d-5"]'.extract())
         with open("asdf.txt",'wb') as f:
             f.write(u"".join(x).encode("UTF-8"))
```

But the scrapy crawls a web page different from the one specified.I got this on the command prompt:

```
2016-08-15 14:00:14 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=jaslyn%20california> (referer: None)
```

but the URL I specified is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/people/?q=jaslyn%20california
```

Comment: If you are looking for why your spider doesn't find any results it's because facebook is very javascript heavy and makes couple dozen AJAX requests for every page. I'd highly recommend using facebook's api.

Comment: Scraping Facebook pages is against their ToS. If you want any information from Facebook, use their API.

Answer (score 2):

Scraping is not allowed on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

If you want to get data from Facebook, you have to use their Graph API. For example, this would be the API to search for users: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search

It is not as powerful as the Graph Search on facebook.com though.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is redirecting the request to the new url.

Comment: Why is it redirecting ? I can open the link just fine. Can I force it to crawl the same web page ?

Answer (score 0):

it seems as though you are missing some headers in your request.

```
2016-08-15 14:00:14 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=jaslyn%20california> (referer: None)
```

as you can see the referer is None, I would advise you add some headers manually, [namely the referer](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects).